# Getting Error Data should be a "String", "Array of arrays" OR "Array of objects" when trying to export data to CSV in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to download some data that I have from my firebase firestore DB that I have listed in a table.

I am adding the data that is coming from my firestore in order to export to CSV and have a complete viewable file in my admin dashboard

But every time I try to follow the steps to download the data and export them to CSV format I get this error: `"Data should be a "String", "Array of arrays" OR "Array of objects"`

here is my code:

```
 import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [csvData, setcsvData] = useState([]);
  const list = []
  const csvList = []

 useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Users").get().then((userSnapshot) => {

      userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        const {powerAccount,first_name,registerDate,email,company,country,phone} = doc.data();
        setID(doc.data().usersID)
        list.push({
          usersID:doc.id,
          powerAccount:powerAccount,
          first_name:first_name,
          registerDate:registerDate,
          email:email,
          company:company,
          country:country,
          phone:phone,
        });

        const userData = {
          usersID: doc.id,
          powerAccount: powerAccount,
          first_name: first_name,
          registerDate: registerDate,
          email: email,
          company: company,
          country: country,
          phone: phone,
        };

        const headers = [            
          { label: 'Account', key: powerAccount },
          { label: 'Name', key: first_name },
          { label: 'RegistrationDate', key: registerDate },
          { label: 'Email', key: email },
          { label: 'Company', key: company },
          { label: 'Country', key: country },
          { label: 'Phone', key: phone },
        ];
        const csvReport = {
          filename: "userReport.csv",
          headers: headers,
          data: userData
        }
        csvList.push(csvReport)
      });
      setData(list);
      setcsvData(csvList)
    });
  },[]);

 return (
   
    <CSVLink  {...csvData} >
    Export
  </CSVLink>
 
)
```

Comment: Could you add the stack trace error in order to know better where the error might come from?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by adding a conditional wrapper around my CSVLink component so that it didn't try to create that component before the data was loaded.

So, for your example, something like this could do the trick:

```
{csvData && (
    <CSVLink  {...csvData} >
    Export
  </CSVLink>
)}
```